# Can electric flux lines touch at any point?

Tags: probability, field-theory

Since electric flux lines do not cut, is it possible for them to touch at any point or not.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If Electric Fields cut each other at any point, then this would imply that at a given point, the Electric field has two different directions (recall that the direction of the Electric Field at each point is tangent to the direction of Field Line), which of course is not possible. Hence, the Electric Field lines never cut each other at any point in space.

Comment: What if they are tangent ?

Comment: The answer is almost correct. The lines can touch at infinity (they are tangent there), otherwise I should be able to squeeze one more field line between any two. The only option to have touching filed lines is to have a point-like charge at the intersection point

Comment: What about a time dependent electric field? What prevents the field lines to intersect as much as they want?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one case where field lines can "touch," in a sense.  Suppose you have two electric point charges of the same sign an arbitrary distance apart.  There will be a point along the line between their centers where the electric field will be zero.  But near that point along that line the field will be nonzero and aimed along that same line.

So if you draw field lines originating at both charges, they will aim right along that line from both directions and will come together at that point where the field is zero.  So do they "touch" or just come really close to touching?  Is guess it depends on what you define as "touching."